# Sorting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I am trying to sort a week column with the datatype `varchar` because the weeks are in this format `2017_6, 2017_7`. As we all know SQL sorts `varchar` numbers like `2017_1, 2017_10, 2017_11` etc.

How can I get it to sort numerically, without changing the weeks format? I tried `nvarchar` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is to use the length:

```
order by len(weekcol), weekcol
```

For multiple years:

```
order by left(weekcol, 4), len(weekcol), weekcol
```

Comment: Nice little trick. Some explanations why this will work will help the OP ;)

Comment: Order by len works however i still have weeks from 2016 that need to appear before week 2017_1.

Answer (score 0):

you can also sort by this field length. e.g:

```
SELECT ........ order by len(myfield),myfield
```

Answer (score 0):

Trick using [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql), this will work with any year range:

```
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(Replace(ColumnName, '_', '.'), 2) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(Replace(ColumnName, '_', '.'), 1) AS INT);
```

Sample execution with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (MonthValue VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (MonthValue) VALUES
('2017_6'), ('2017_7'),  ('2016_12'), ('2017_10'), ('2017_11');

SELECT *
FROM @TestTable
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(Replace(MonthValue, '_', '.'), 2) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(Replace(MonthValue, '_', '.'), 1) AS INT)
```

Result:

```
2016_12
2017_6
2017_7
2017_10
2017_11
```